# Hadn't/haven't- difference in meaning in the given context

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, tense, usage, tense-agreement

> 1. Life would be so much easier if people could anticipate your needs and work to satisfy them.
>      Like, if somebody got you that cup of coffee you ***hadn't*** asked for yet.
> 2. Life would be so much easier if people could anticipate your needs and work to satisfy them.
>      Like, if somebody got you that cup of coffee you ***haven't*** asked for yet.

Are both *hadn't* and *haven't* usable here?
Does either affect the meaning of the sentence?
Are both grammatically correct?

Comment: The first one implies more of an imperfect version of the sentence, implying you hadn't asked for one in the past, while the second sentence is in present form implying that you have yet to ask for one. The first one isn't technically correct I believe, since hadn't is mostly used in a past sentence instead of a present sentence case like it would be here.

Answer (score 3):

Either tense can work, but it would be better in the second example to change the tense of "got" to match that of "have".

> if somebody **got** you that cup of coffee you **hadn't** asked for yet.
>
> if somebody **gets** you that cup of coffee you **haven't** asked for yet.

However, the first choice better fits the construction of "**would** be so much easier... **could** anticipate...".

Answer (score 0):

**Hadn't** is more grammatically correct. The past perfect tense here indicated by the auxiliary verb *hadn't* denotes (means) an action - *not asking for that cup of coffee yet* - that started before the past happening - *somebody got you that cup of coffee*. That action lasted until the past happening happened. It'd be more like "the past of the past". In this case, it's very clear to know which action/event took place first. The sentence as a whole implies an unreal present, which makes the two sentences more coherent (linked) as the followed sentence also implies a similar case - Life *would* be so much easier if people *could*...

**Haven't**, on the other hand, sounds a bit ambiguous (unclear). It indicates the present perfect tense, which doesn't make much sense when it follows the past tense indicating by *got*. It also breaks the construction made by the followed sentence.